# Partial code completion PHPStorm CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpstorm

**(PHPStorm version 8.0.3 with CodeIgniter 3, running on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.3)**

As the title states, I currently experience partial code completion.

At first I had nothing, I used the following link to add the partial part:

1. https://github.com/topdown/phpStorm-CC-Helpers/blob/master/README.md#using-the-my_modelsphp (It works for me without and with the 'marking as plain text' solution)

I can now for example see the code completion for `$this->...`, thus giving me options at first I didn't had.

I do get an 'unfound' method warning message from PHPStorm when I use `$query->row_array();` after assigning `$query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));`. So in this case my code completion doesn't work (It can't find it).

The full code of this class is found beneath.

```
class News_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
    {
        if($slug === FALSE)
        {
            $query = $this->db->get('news');

            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));

        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

When I run a search for the method 'row_array' it is found under 'System' > 'database' > 'db_result.php'. So it is defined, but PHPStorm can't give me code completion

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you actually asked anyone at JetBrains?  They do have a knowledge base and an active community forum: https://www.jetbrains.com/devnet/phpstorm/

Comment: The problem is that PHPStorm does not know what the object is that is returned from the `$this->db->get(...);` or `$this->db->query(...)` so it cannot show any autocomplete methods. I'm not sure this will be very easy achieve, the only thing I can think is to change some data in the DB_active_rec.php and DB_driver.php `@return object` to `@return CI_DB_result` on the query(), get() and any other methods you want. This might not even work so good luck :) Also this is not ideal because if you update these file you will lose your autocomplete.

Comment: @mic Okay that makes more sense, it's still driving me crazy, there has to be a other solution for this right? Are you experiencing something different with CI and PHPStorm or do you use another IDE? I tried Sublime but that isn't working for me either

Comment: I was using PHPStorm but I recently moved over to Atom which has even less autocomplete on non composer frameworks. You could try put a comment block above the $query var something like /* @var $query CI_DB_Result */ which might make it know that the var is an object. I seem to remember doing that with PHPStorm to get it autocompleting. Let me know if that works for you :)

Comment: @mic Thanks for your reply, sadly it still doesn't work with your solution... Anything else?

Comment: see my answer, its tested and working :)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding.

As long as you followed one of these options

> Option 1 =
>   File > Settings > Directories > Add Content Root > Select the directory in phpStorm-CC-helpers that is relevant > mark Resource Root
>
> Option 2 =
>   In the project window right click External Libraries > Configure PHP Include Paths Then add the path to the phpStorm-CC-helpers that is relevant

Then according to the helper annotations `/CI_DB_active_record` is what it is returned when you call `get_where`. Ensure that the file `/system/database/DB_active_rec.php` is marked as plain text so that the IDE can parse it for autocomplete.

If you are using CodeIgniter 3, `/system/database/DB_active_rec.php` and the `/CI_DB_active_record` class was removed from the CodeIgniter source, so there would be no reference found for `/CI_DB_active_record` that the helper references.

Comment: I am indeed using CodeIgniter 3, but the solutions that were given to me won't work in the readme or whatever are not working

Comment: Considering the helpers you linked were last updated 2 years ago, I highly doubt they are applicable to `CI3`as CI3 was released April of 2015. See: http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-61799.html The helpers are litterally overriding the default documentation for the CI source inside of PHPStorm.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it I can confirm that it does work, its not ideal but it will produce autocomplete for the $query var.

I used this in the route of my project.
https://gist.github.com/gentoid/4353692

Then you have to do the code like this:

```
public function index($slug)
{
    /** @var CI_DB_result $query */
    $query = $this->db->get();

    //this will now produce auto complete in PHPStorm because 
    //it knows that object the $query var contains.
    //$query->
}
```

also you can do this

```
/**
 * @return CI_DB_result
 */
public function getData()
{
    return $this->db->get();
}

public function test()
{
    $query = $this->getData();

    //this will now produce auto complete in PHPStorm because 
    //it knows that object the $query var contains.
    //$query->
}
```